# Print first 40 elements in a list ordered by value

Tags: java

I still am not getting the top 40 le t me show you my code:

```
Map<String, Integer> doubleCount= new HashMap<>();
SortedMap<String,Integer> newMap= new TreeMap<>(doubleCount);
Map<String,Integer> newDouble40 = newMap.headMap("40"); 
System.out.println(newDouble40);
```

this is giving me an empty list, and more than that it does not sort it.... so I sorted it :

```
public static <K extends Comparable,V extends Comparable> Map<K,V> sortByValues(Map<K,V> map){
   List<Map.Entry<K,V>> entries = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K,V>>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<K, V> o1, Entry<K, V> o2) {
            return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    });
     Map<K,V> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K,V>();

    for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry: entries){
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return sortedMap;
}
```

but HOW DO I print the first 40?.... if you use the code above and say:

```
 System.out.println(sortByValues(doubleCount));
```

you get a sorted hashMap by value.

but HOW DO I PRINT ONLY THE FIRST 40????

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int i = 0;
for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry: sortByValues(doubleCount)){
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
    if (++i == 40) break;
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use

```
"public Collection<V> values()"
```

function of HashMap to get all values then use

```
for(int i=0; i<40; i++){System.out.println(valuelist.get(i))}
```